# Tauri toggle app visibility on tray icon click

Tags: rust, contextmenu, system-tray, tauri

I am creating a small app, which I want to work as a "tray app". What I mean is I don't want to show a dock icon, only a tray icon.

I want the app window to be visible when the app first opens.

then when the users close the app by clicking on the window's `X` button, the app should close (minimize). The same should happen if the users left-click on the tray icon.

If the app is already minimized, clicking on the tray icon should show again the app window.

I would like the tray menu to be visible only when the users right-click on the tray icon.

**in short:**

- tray icon left click: toggle app visibility (don't show the menu)
- tray icon right click: show "app tray context menu" (don't toggle app's visibility)

This is my first time using Tauri and using Rust, so I am kind of lost.

By searching around and trying different things I come to this (on my `src-tauri/src/main.rs` file):

```rs
#![cfg_attr(
    all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
    windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]


use tauri::{Manager, CustomMenuItem, SystemTray, SystemTrayMenu, SystemTrayMenuItem, SystemTrayEvent};

fn main() {
    let quit = CustomMenuItem::new("quit".to_string(), "Quit");
    let hide = CustomMenuItem::new("hide".to_string(), "Hide");

    let tray_menu = SystemTrayMenu::new()
        .add_item(quit)
        .add_native_item(SystemTrayMenuItem::Separator)
        .add_item(hide);
    let tray = SystemTray::new().with_menu(tray_menu);

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .on_system_tray_event(|app, event| match event {
            SystemTrayEvent::LeftClick { .. } => {
                let window = match app.get_window("main") {
                    Some(window) => match window.is_visible().expect("winvis") {
                        true => {
                            // hide the window instead of closing due to processes not closing memory leak: https://github.com/tauri-apps/wry/issues/590
                            window.hide().expect("winhide");
                            // window.close().expect("winclose");
                            return;

                        }
                        false => window,
                    },
                    None => return,
                };
                #[cfg(not(target_os = "macos"))]
                {
                    window.show().unwrap();
                }
                window.set_focus().unwrap();
            }
            _ => {}
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

This toggles the app's visibility on left click, but it also shows the "context menu".

Any ideas on how to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

> This toggles the app's visibility on left click, but it also shows the "context menu".

You can configure this (for macOS) in the tauri.conf.json file: https://tauri.app/v1/api/config/#systemtrayconfig.menuonleftclick
It would look something like this

```json
{
  "tauri": {
    "systemTray": {
      "iconPath": "icons/icon.png",
      "menoOnLeftClick": false
    }
  }
}
```

And a bit more info about the other platforms:

- This is the default (and only) behavior on Windows.
- This is not possible on Linux because of a limitation (design decision) of libappindicator (that's why the LeftClick event is not emitted on Linux). So in case you wanna support Linux too you probably have to resort to a Menu-based alternative .

Comment: This sounds exactly like what i want. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe the problem be on my main.rs somehow overriding this setting?

Comment: Nope, unrelated to your main.rs file. I totally forgot about it but there was a regression in 1.1 which was fixed on git and will be part of 1.2 which we plan to release this week.